# Check `Restore on AC/Power Loss` from CMD/Powershell on windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-command-prompt

I've set the Restore on AC/Power Loss from the windows Bios menu on computer startup for a few Windows machines.

How can someone confirm (remotely) that I have done that, is there a way to do this from a remote desktop?

Bonus points if you know how to change it remotely (if it can be done).

What I've done:

- Ran `wmic bios get /format:list` but saw nothing that fit.
- Looked through documents, such as [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) and [the wmic documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but haven't know what to be looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found `WakeUpType` property of the [`Win32_ComputerSystem` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx)

> **WakeUpType**
>
> Data type: `uint16`
>  Access type: `Read-only`
>  Qualifiers:
>   MappingStrings ("`SMBIOS|Type 1|System Information|Wake-up Type`")
>
> Event that causes the system to power up.
>
> This value comes from the *Wake-up Type* member of the *System
>   Information* structure in the *SMBIOS* information.
>
> ```
> - Reserved (0)
> - Other (1)
> - Unknown (2)
> - APM Timer (3)
> - Modem Ring (4)
> - LAN Remote (5)
> - Power Switch (6)
> - PCI PME# (7)
> - AC Power Restored (8)
> ```

Read [System Management BIOS (SMBIOS) Reference Specification](http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.0.0.pdf) as well.

Next script requires following adjustments to satisfy (your) particular  operational circumstances:

- `$computers` array (e.g. read it from a file);
- `$WakeUpType = Get-WmiObject` (e.g. add `-Authentication` or `-Credential` etc. parameters, see [`Get-Help 'Get-WmiObject' -ShowWindow`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/a3470de7-e427-4bd1-8a97-6e9d22a01da6(v=wps.630).aspx)).

---

```
$WakeUpTypes = DATA {ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData @’
    0 = Reserved          (0)
    1 = Other             (1)
    2 = Unknown           (2)
    3 = APM Timer         (3)
    4 = Modem Ring        (4)
    5 = LAN Remote        (5)
    6 = Power Switch      (6)
    7 = PCI PME#          (7)
    8 = AC Power Restored (8)
   na = ? unreachable ? (N/A)
‘@}

$computers  = ".", "$env:COMPUTERNAME", ### I *know* that these are the same 
              "bububu"                  ### and this is fake name for debugging

$namespace = "ROOT\CIMV2"
$classname = "Win32_ComputerSystem"

ForEach ( $computer in $computers ) {
    Try {
          $WakeUpType = Get-WmiObject `
            -Class $classname -ComputerName $computer -Namespace $namespace `
            -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
          $WakeUpName = $WakeUpTypes.Item("$($WakeUpType.WakeUpType)")
    } Catch {
          $WakeUpName = $WakeUpTypes.Item("na") 
    }
    If ( $WakeUpName -eq $null ) { $WakeUpName = "Undefined as yet ($WakeUpType)" }
    "{0,-20} {1}" -f $computer, $WakeUpName
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run in PowerShell

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -Property e,WakeUpType
```