# Is there a way to check "boot after power loss" BIOS configuration from CLI?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, bios, dmidecode

Is there a way to check from CLI under linux (Debian based) how the BIOS is configured for "boot on power loss" ? I need something similar to [Check `Restore on AC/Power Loss` from CMD/Powershell on windows 10](https://serverfault.com/questions/777377/check-restore-on-ac-power-loss-from-cmd-powershell-on-windows-10) but for linux.

I had a look at `dmidecode` and `biosdecode` commands but found nothing sor far (to be honest I don't really know what to look for).

Rationale: verify remotely if servers will boot up on power recovery after a power failure without having to reboot them and enter their BIOS to do the verification.

Comment: AFIAK there is no generic interface that makes bios settings directly accessible to the running OS. I think we for example use our iDrac access to make such adjustments https://serverfault.com/a/824792/984089